# How to add a column of aggregated values in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I want to add a column to my dataframe that displays frequency sums based on age group so I can calculate percentages as an additional column afterward.
Right now I have two dataframes, the one I want to work with

| Residential Status | age_group | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50-59 | 5327 |
| 1 | 60-69 | 1962 |
| 1 | 70-79 | 224 |
| 1 | 80-85 | 16 |
| 2 | 50-59 | 1260 |
| 2 | 60-69 | 1176 |
| 2 | 70-79 | 428 |
| 2 | 80-85 | 75 |
| ... |  |  |

and the one that has the aggregate values.

| age_group | group total |
| --- | --- |
| 50-59 | 117812 |
| 60-69 | 71868 |
| 70-79 | 18796 |
| 80-85 | 6310 |

I want it to look like this:

| Residential Status | age_group | frequency | group total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50-59 | 5327 | 117812 |
| 1 | 60-69 | 1962 | 71868 |
| 1 | 70-79 | 224 | 18796 |
| 1 | 80-85 | 16 | 6310 |
| 2 | 50-59 | 1260 | 117812 |
| 2 | 60-69 | 1176 | 71868 |
| 2 | 70-79 | 428 | 18796 |
| 2 | 80-85 | 75 | 6310 |

I have tried using merge(), but it's literally adding the second dataframe on top of the first. I also tried to use summarise(), but that didn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: `merge(your_first_data_frame, your_second_data_frame, by = "age_group")` should work just fine. Or with `dplyr` `first_data_frame |> left_join(second_data_frame)`. It would be nice to see what code you tried that didn't work. Perhaps your `age_group` columns are different classes in the different data frames? Maybe `factor` in one and `character` in another? Or `factor` classes with different levels? If you convert them both to `character` class with `as.character()` that would solve that problem.

Comment: If you still have trouble after that, inspect the values closely in the `age_group` column to make sure you don't have unneeded white space like `"80-85 "`, or other irregularities. If you still have the issue, please edit your question to share the sample data with `dput()`, e.g., `dput(your_first_data_frame[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows of one data frame. That will include all data structure information so we can inspect more closely.